# Structure pointer initialized with a value behaves like enum

Tags: c++, arm

I was reading an [article regarding bare bones programming of ARM processor](https://github.com/cpq/bare-metal-programming-guide) when I came across the following code

```cpp
struct systick {
  volatile uint32_t CTRL, LOAD, VAL, CALIB;
};
#define SYSTICK ((struct systick *) 0xe000e010)

#define BIT(x) (1UL << (x))

static inline void systick_init(uint32_t ticks) {
  if ((ticks - 1) > 0xffffff) return;  // Systick timer is 24 bit
  SYSTICK->LOAD = ticks - 1;
  SYSTICK->VAL = 0;
  SYSTICK->CTRL = BIT(0) | BIT(1) | BIT(2);  // Enable systick
  RCC->APB2ENR |= BIT(14);                   // Enable SYSCFG
}
```

I am not able to understand how does initializing a pointer to a structure initialize variables inside a structure? Does the ARM compiler treat it as an enum?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very likely a memory-mapped device. So, when you write to structure members, you're essentially manipulating the hardware, just as with port output (but in this case, memory-mapped). So you're essentially writing to a hardware that's available on addresses `0xe000e010`, `0xe000e014`, `0xe000e018`, `0xe000e01c` respectively for `CTRL`, `LOAD`, `VAL`, `CALIB`. Then you set particular bits manually.